# Two different answers using different methods, combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is set with $n$ elements, we take one, write what we get, put element back to set, we do this operation $r$ times. What is the probability that each element was taken exactly once. Assume $n \geq r$ else probability is $0$

I get two different answers using two methods. I want to know which one is correct, and why other method is wrong.

First method:

Represent elemnts as strings of length $n$ and numer of times they were chosen by pluses. We want to give $r$ pluses to $n$ elements. There are ${r+n-1 \choose r}$ possibilities. Our desired event are strings with $r$ one and $n-r$ zeros. There are ${n \choose r}$ possibilites. So the probability is $\frac{{n \choose r}}{r+n-1 \choose n-1}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)}{(r+n-1)(r+n-2)(r+n-3)...(n)}$

Second method:

We take first element $n$ possiblites, then second $n$ possiblities, then third $n$ possiblites ... r-th elemnt $n$ possiblites, so there are $n^r$ possibilites of choosing $r$ elements. Our desired event happens when we take first elment $n$ possiblites then for second choice we only have $n-1$ possibilities, for the third element $n-2$ possbilites, for r-th element $n-r+1$ possiblities, so the probability is $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1}{n^r}$

Comment: I don't understand the first method.  I suggest:  look at the smallest case for which the answers are different.  This will be a very small case.  Write out all possible outcomes and analyze them versus the two methods you have proposed.

Comment: Oh, is the first method a Stars and Bars computation?  But the outcomes counted by that method are not equally probable.  It's very hard to use that method in probability questions.  Usually not worth the effort.

Comment: so the second method is correct?

Comment: Yes, I see no problems with the second method.

Comment: I will try to look at small case and see if I can find why the first method doesn't work but maybe someone is able to provide an answer in general?

Comment: My second comment explains the problem, trusting that you were trying for a Stars and Bars approach...what you wrote is pretty terse.  You simply can't use that method for probability, as the outcomes are not equally probable.  In theory, you can correct for that, but the corrections are brutal.  Usually a bad plan.

Comment: Yes I was trying to do Start and Bars approach. What do you mean outcomes are not equally probable?

Comment: In the case $n=r=2,$ call the elements $A$ and $B,$ and $a$ and $b$ be the number of times each is chosen. Then $(a,b)$ can be $(2,0),$ $(1,1),$ or $(0,2),$ which are the $\binom{2+2-1}{2}=3$ outcomes counted by stars and bars. But when you pull the elements from the set and write their names one after the other, you get $AA,$ $AB,$ $BA,$ or $BB.$ There are two ways to get each element once, but only one way to get the first element twice.

Comment: I mean that the outcomes are not equally probable.  If you toss two fair dice the probability of getting a sum of $2$ is not the same as the probability of throwing a $3$.  That's because you can get $(1,1)$ in only one way but you can get $(1,2)$ in two ways.